# How can I prevent IIS Express starting when attaching to IIS process?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I do not want use IIS Express.

My IIS always running.

I do not want to turn on IIS Express every debug/attach to process.

How to set IIS Express always off?

I always use attach to process to debug my project

[image: Attach]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent iisexpress from running the websites in a solution when the startup app is a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330919/prevent-iisexpress-from-running-the-websites-in-a-solution-when-the-startup-app)

Answer (score 4):

Select your web project in solution explorer and set `Always Start When Debugging` to `false`.

Comment: Use "F4" to access this project property setting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330919/prevent-iisexpress-from-running-the-websites-in-a-solution-when-the-startup-app/#32900552